What is the artistic animation style with extremely few frames to tell the story called?
What is the artistic animation style with extremely few frames to tell the story called?
note, i'm not talking about the style of  essentially a slideshow (Hangman cartoon mentioned in the comments falls in that category). The motion is still depicted, even though the gaps between the frames are big, there's still a relatively "one" movement between two frames that can be clearly understood (i.e. a bird opens its wings, or a man raises his arms). There IS motion — just there are only KEY frames.
So, say, if in the story a bird flies away, a slideshow-style cartoon would show just one still of a bird flying away, a regular cartoon, say, 20–30 frames, while the style I'm looking for — maybe 3 frames, with 1-second pauses between them.
There can be some transition between these key frames - cross-fade, for example, or something more artistic - but no extra frames with transitional position of the moving body.
I saw it in some relatively old avant-garde cartoons. I remember it as very impressive and emotional, but I don't remember any titles, and searching without knowing specific terms leads me nowhere.
Maybe you know the term for this specific (sub)genre or technique, or some examples of it?
While browsing some underground animation on YouTube now, I only find works that use it sparingly, example:



The link is to the exact moment, but if the video starts from the beginning, just skip to 2:23–2:54.
The main character's childhood memories that are presented in a pink circle are almost all done this way, BUT! after 2:54, the events depicted by consecutive frames are already not immediately close in time/space, so there it's already a slideshow.
The example seems to be a student work, but I'm certain I've seen very artistic works using this technique.

"While browsing some underground animation on YouTube now, I only find works that use it sparingly" Can you [edit] your question and add links to those YouTube videos?

One example would be The Hangman (1964)

@Steve, thank you, this is a great poem and an interesting cartoon. It is not exactly what I'm looking for (i described in the edit of the question), but i'm glad you suggested it - it's impressive.

@blobbymcblobby - the term is "photomontage". It's used quite a lot in films; https://youtu.be/w_BhRQmRurs?si=4LlMe3_GWNAQsW4P

https://youtu.be/vfsK8rgtOl0?si=VqK4eCeTiBzRwNL3 the airport scene is a good example

@Valorum - i dismissed that as i was looking for something more specific to what the OP might have meant (though The Pier was already included in my old answer).

So whilst I was more narrow in my thoughts, Valorum opted for photomontage which might get you there, though I thought you were looking for something more specific to the technique. As an ex animator that was what I was heading for. (When you have more reputation you can look at the deleted answer anyway - which also inluded 1962's La Jetee)

@Valorum thank you! unfortunately: photomontage has an encyclopedic meaning, so, even if it is ALSO a name of a style, i don't know how it'd be possible to search for the works that use it; 2) French movie is a "literal slideshow", like the Hangman; no motion there 3) Cocaine movie, while curious) and has plenty of close frames, is still NOT it)) sorry - those frames are independent, none of them are 2 keyframes of a single movement

I've voted to reopen since you've added to your answer, hope someone more knowledgeable can provide an answer in the future. Curious, do you do animation yourself? Just asking, as I had a few books in the past but aside from the obvious terms I cannot remember something specific to this, it was just part of what we did for dramatic effect for example (or used the 'animatic' look - part of your example looked sketchy, so bringing an unfinished aesthetic into it as well (which also leads to the animatic look), though I understand that wasn't your focus).

@darkdiatel - You can see an entire film in photomontage here. There are sequences where multiple photos are taken and then placed in sequence to show movement without actually filming; https://youtu.be/xcIKN_t3bCY?si=zZwlDjYVoil8VHPz&t=54

on a technical level you're simply cross-fading between frames on a timeline.. which is a montage. Simply drop the 'photo'-bit, as that might be misleading, as you were talking about animation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montage_(filmmaking)  "montage sequence", used primarily by British and American studios, became the common technique to suggest the passage of time.

@Valorum - thank you. perhaps this term is instantly understood between film professionals, but i'm trying to search for animation - drawn images, so this term doesn't work (I tried). perhaps technically what you show IS what I'm asking for - just, obviously there's natural difference between what artists would draw and what experimental directors would shoot. Perhaps if they did something on the subject of ballet, the feeling would be closer.
I am keeping my search just going through less known animation from 80s/90s, if I find exactly what I'm looking for, i'll update my question.

@darkdiatel - I don't know what to tell you. The fact that it's an animated film doesn't make it any more or less of a photomontage. That's just what it is.

@blobbymcblobby thank you very much! This article helps, indeed there's a confusion about this term. p.s. I am not animator at all (except for very technical flash animation for work long ago). I'm a musician and searching for the cartoons of this style as a reference for a collaboration with an artist.

darkdiatel i straddled both decades ago so my memory is a little leaky. I think dropping the term to simply montage (literally assembly in french) helped a little to open up the floor. It is still film-making leaning rather than animation-technique specific (which may lead you to..stop-motion..?) but it may help!

and so in addition to the above, a stop-motion animation - https://youtu.be/pwJqpwWUZt0 (on a point of labor, the thought of doing this on 1s or 2s is quite painful..)

@blobbymcblobby i watched this one just today! i didn't post it as example because it's rather traditional - it has plenty of frames for most movements. but it has something in common namely the artistic drawing and similar transitions

yes, the transitions is what puts it into the montage territory, whereas stop motion might have each frame shown as is with no over-lap, no transition, and so as a technique to 'add' frames to motion inbetween the keyframes, we lengthen the time the frame is exposed on the timeline and use this extra space with which to create the transtion into the next frame, making it appear smoother than if it was 'just' stop-motion. Star Wars also tried to 'blend' in between its stop motion, using 'go-motion', blurring the inbetweens, so less like Harryhausen

@blobbymcblobby To be a film montage, it also must compress time, space, and information. As accurately described by Team America.

well, tbh, I did say it further up the comments, just trying to get to an idea of what you call what the OP is talking about. The closest i can think of is an animated animatic with transitions ...

Animatic
That's a type of storyboard called an "animatic".

Often storyboards are animated with simple zooms and pans to simulate camera movement (using non-linear editing software). These animations can be combined with available animatics, sound effects, and dialog to create a presentation of how a film could be shot and cut together.

Animatics are used during production, but they can also be the final product: an inexpensive way to suggest animation without all the expense of doing actual animation. As a result, YouTube is loaded with them as a way to produce animations within their limited budgets.
Here's an example...



It isn't a montage.
Montages and photomontages were discussed in the comments.
While the OP's short is a series of still images edited together, the essential part of a film montage is that it uses the juxtaposition of images or clips to create new meaning not present in the original clips. The OP's example does the opposite; the images are related and are edited together to enhance their meaning.
The term has drifted significantly over the years. It's French for "assembly". In early Soviet filmmaking, a montage was a juxtaposition of images and clips; the juxtaposition, rather than the content of the clips, gives the intended meaning. Here's Alfred Hitchcock explaining this effect.



The modern meaning is accurately explained in Team America; a montage is a storytelling technique to compress time, space, and/or information. It was made cliche by training sequences in American action movies.



It isn't a photomontage. In still photography it is a technique where a new photo is made by splicing together other photos.

In film it can be used to mean a film montage created using photos, as in La Jetée.

thank you for telling about this. Do i understand correctly that this phenomenon is strictly from the computer animation era? Form your description it seems so

@darkdiatel animatics have been around since traditional animation started, as part of the pre production process. It was a way to get a sense of timing from the storyboard. Given that literally any style can be used in animation, sketchy lines, artwork not cleaned up, and the animatic, all of them themselves can be final product, which is i think, the suggestion from this answer...

@darkdiatel Animatics have been around for probably as long as there has been animation. Computers make them easier to make and add a sense of motion. The Internet makes them easier to distribute.
